# What services go on what server in a farm configuration?

Tags: sharepoint-server, configuration, server-farm

I am configuring a 5 server farm for SharePoint 2013.
WFE1
WFE2
APP1
WAC1(OWA)
SQL1

I am trying to figure out what should get provisioned where using AutoSPInstaller.  Do I provision Claims on all servers?  Or just the WFE? Workflow Timer Service just on the APP1 server?

I am also wondering if I can/should configure Search on the Web Apps (WAC) server?

Thanks for any help

Comment: which version of sharepoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put any other service on the WAC server. It will run WAC and WAC only.

Timer Service should be on the APP server. Claims isn't something you configure on a per-server basis. It is configured for the Web Application.

Take a look at [Streamlined topologies for SharePoint Server 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=37000) to get an idea of what services to put where, but you don't have the capability of having a highly available setup for services with only a single APP server, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, nice concise answers. I only could get funding for 5 servers and figured this was the best configuration for now.  APP2 will be the first additional server we add. I have that document and a few other links that are great but it's these Farm Services that are throwing me for a loop. I also was confused by why I was prompted to provision claims.  Happy knowing WAC is WAC and WFT is on the APP server.

Comment: For anyone else a little stuck on configuration, the linked article helped when I found the Traditional Topology section half way down. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219591.aspx#Section1

Comment: I would not use the traditional model regardless. It puts even fewer services with a 2 + 1 setup in a highly available configuration and has higher latency for end users working with SharePoint.

Comment: Thanks Trevor - learning in progress for sure.  I wish I had done more research up front (but to be honest I did a ton as it is) but I have already configured the farm.  How hard is it to reconfigure the servers?  I am debating the "start fresh while I can" vs the re-arrange when we get the second App server.

Comment: For Service Instances, super easy. Just stop them where you need to and start them where you need to. E.g. if you started the MMS service instance on the APP server, stop it there, and start it on the two FEs. This is under Central Admin -> Manage Services on Server. Search is the "tough" one, as you have to provision where to run what services via PowerShell.

Comment: Ok perfect, that was my hunch based on what I knew regarding Service Instances.  Search and UPS have been a major PITA since I got into SharePoint.  Always a good challenge. I'll re-provision search then when we get that second APP server.  Your help has been great! Thanks